# Standard Object Permissions for Read-only profile

Tags: owd

For what this standard profile has for example for Account standard object access to read (without any other permissions) records? What kind of records this profile is able to read?

I'm investigating OWD's and have faced the same problem - Why standard profile "ReadOnly" for standard object "Account" has only read permission? As was mentioned above - what if the user assigned to this profile will try to read accounts?

What will be the results?

Comment: The question is very vague. Could you please modify it and add some more context ?

Comment: I've modified (I hope) my question

Comment: Are you asking why "ReadOnly" only has "Read" permissions?

Comment: Yeap, clearly about this

Comment: Two worthwhile resources: 1) [The Who Sees What video series](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2017/data-visibility-made-easy-updated-video-series) (really, really excellent, I recommend seeing all of them) and 2) [A Guide to Sharing Architecture](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sharing_architecture.pdf) (a dense read, but the pyramid on page 2 shows you what's at play when it comes to what a user can see)

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests its a **Read-Only**, so no other permission will be there by default. Provided that the user has a record level permission, it will be able to read/Query the records.

---

- Q. What if the user assigned to this profile will try to read
  accounts?
- Q. What kind of records this profile is able to read?

The answer to both questions is the same and based on Record Level permission like below,

### If the OWD is Public Read/Read Write -

The user with the **Read-Only** profile can **read** all the records.

### If the OWD Private -

The users with **Read-Only** profile can read the record if any of these conditions satisfy.

- User is the Owner of Record
- The record is manually shared with the user.
- The record is shared with the user by using Sharing Rule.
- The record is shared with the user by using Apex Sharing.

In case if you want to give edit access to only a specific Object/s only, while keeping other objects **Read-Only**, you can clone the Read-Only profile and grant the Edit access to those objects using this cloned profile.